What are some good choices for permeable root barriers for raised garden beds?
I just had my soil tested and it's not suitable for growing veges. It bordering the threshhold for lead. (green leafy vegetables tend to absorb the lead) The lab suggested that I build raised beds and add a permeable root barrier so that roots won't reach the ground soil.
What are some options for permeable root barriers?
I see some synthetic ones, I can't seem to find any natural ones...maybe they are not advertised as root barriers (for example, a bed of rocks).
Is a weed barrier basically function as a root barrier? Will it prevent roots from growing down?
What are some good options based on people's experience?

What, precisely, do you mean by "natural" here? Anything that will biodegrade is not going to be a root barrier.

Could like a bed of rocks be a good natural root barrier?  Will the roots grow past into the crevices of between the rocks?

That will barely slow them down, and will fill with dirt eventually as well.

"Permeable root barrier" is self-contradictory, there is no such thing.

I was research and found this.  CuTex Copper Composite Root Barrier.  Way out of my price range.  This uses chemistry to thwart root growth when it approaches a copper ion barrier.  Crazy!

So, your soil is contaminated with things the roots should not take up for growing food.
In  that case, concrete or cor-ten steel planters with drainage holes is about as "permeable" as you want to risk, IMHO. Drainage holes on the sides, or out the bottom only if the planter is elevated on legs. No direct ground contact. I suppose you could make an elevated untreated wood planter if you enjoy replacing things that rot every few years.
Or, large plant pots (terra cotta clay is pretty "natural") (or half-barrels, but rot does happen with wood) as planters, again, elevated from direct soil contact.
From personal experience, "weed barrier" is a misnomer for that particular fabric product, and weeds that germinate on top of it quite happily root through it into the the soil beneath. Things known to work as root barriers (i.e. for containing running bamboo roots) are not permeable - pond liner and sheet metal are typical.

Interesting... didn't think about elevating with legs.  Was thinking about 8' x 4' beds... so that would be a really big planter on legs...I would have to support it throughout the bottom.  I think I'm still going to lean towards having it be open bottom and try to add a barrier.

Landscape fabric? Window Screening? Layers? The biodegradable version would be several layers of newsprint; it would last a few years before degrading .

@milesmeow   8x4 beds will almost have to be on the ground, since they will be too heavy.  Making much smaller beds and they can be raised up.  Saving all the bending over/your knees.  Most plants will be happy with one foot wide beds.
